# async.await is not working in synchronous way?

Tags: mongoose, async-await

Everyone I'm beginner in NODE'S. I tried simple program to insert two documents in Mongoose.My code is working fine.two documents are inserted in db correctly but At the time of retrieving only one document retrieved.I want to call the resolve function once two documents are saved in db.But here after one document saved itself resolve function called back.I want to run this code in **SYNC WAY(ONE BY ONE)**.i.e I used **async-await concept.** Even though it's working in async way.My conclusion is once for loop is get over then only I have to call resolve function.can anyone solve this problem.I attached the code below and my output and expected output.

```html
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var mongoose = require('mongoose');


mongoose.connect("mongodb://DWWW:RFEFE,@ds141902.mlab.com:41902/skyfall",{ useNewUrlParser: true },(err,db)=>{
         if(err)
         {
            return console.log(err.message);
         }
           console.log('db succesfully connected');
});

console.log('ok');

app.use('/', function (req, res) {

    if(req.url ==='/')
    {
        console.log('Request Url:' + req.url);
    
    var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

    var personSchema = new Schema({
        firstname: String,
        lastname: String,
        address: String
    });
    
    var Persondata = mongoose.model('doagain', personSchema);
    
    var data=[{
        firstname: 'John',
        lastname: 'Doe',
        address: '555 Main St.'
       },{
        firstname: 'Jane',
        lastname: 'Doe',
        address: '555 Main St.'
      }];
    var count=1;
    function savingprocess()
    {
        return new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{

               for(var i  in data)
               {
                   var details = Persondata(data[i]);
                   // save the user
                   details.save(function(err) {
                   if (err) reject('ERROR');
                   console.log(' person details saved!:'+count);
                   ++count;
                   });
               }
               resolve('SUCCESS');
               
        });
    }
    async function dosyncway()
    {
       let ans= await savingprocess();
       if(ans ==='SUCCESS')
       {
             // get all the users


      Persondata.find({}, function(err, users) {

   if (err) throw err;
  
        // object of all the users
        console.log("COMPLETE USER DATA:");
        console.log(users);
        res.end('Saved Successfully');
     });
       }
       else{
           console.log('Problem');
       }
    }

    dosyncway();
    }
 
});

app.listen(8086,()=>{
    console.log('server is listening on port:8086');
});


MY OUTPUT:

ok
server is listening on port:8086
db succesfully connected
Request Url:/
 person details saved!:1
COMPLETE USER DATA:
[ { _id: 5bc8cafe54be522c449723d8,
    firstname: 'John',
    lastname: 'Doe',
    address: '555 Main St.',
    __v: 0 } ]
 person details saved!:2
 
 
 I'm expecting output:
 
 ok
server is listening on port:8086
db succesfully connected
Request Url:/
 person details saved!:1
 person details saved!:2
COMPLETE USER DATA:
[ { _id: 5bc8cafe54be522c449723d8,
    firstname: 'John',
    lastname: 'Doe',
    address: '555 Main St.',
    __v: 0 } ,
    { _id: 5bc8cafe54be522c449723d9,
    firstname: 'jane',
    lastname: 'kumar',
    address: 'chennai Main St.',
    __v: 0 }]
 person details saved!:2
```

can anyone update this code ...Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0):

Your **save** calls will execute asynchronously, which is why your promise resolves before all the **save** callbacks are executed.

I think what you are looking for is to add a check in the callback to see if it is the last one to complete, and only then resolve your promise:

```
// ...

for (var i in data) {
  var details = Persondata(data[i]);

  details.save(function(err) {
    if (err) reject('ERROR');

    console.log('person details saved!:' + count);

    // Check if this is the last data item before resolving promise
    if (count === data.length) {
      resolve('SUCCESS');
    }

    ++count;
  });
}
```

---

Alternatively, if you wanted to remove the callbacks, you could use `Promise.all()` to execute all of your save operations together and await the result. Something like this:

```
// ...

function savingProcess() {
  const promises = data.map(item => Persondata(item).save());
  return Promise.all(promises);
}

async function doAsync() {
  try {
    const ans = await savingProcess();
    const users = await Persondata.find({});

    console.log('COMPLETE USER DATA:');
    console.log(users);
    res.end('Saved Successfully');
  }
  catch(err) {
    console.log('Problem');
    throw err;
  }
}

doAsync();
```